# How do I deliver the listname I checked to the textview?

Tags: android, listview

I made a listviewlistener.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView a, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

How do I deliver the listname I checked to the textview?

Comment: Wrap your code in a code block please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ListView contains Strings then all you need to do is...

```
String selectedItem = (String) v.getSelectedItem();
```

EDIT: If you're doing this within a ListActivity then the following might be what you want...

```
String selectedItem = (String) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
```